# SwiftUI: UIViewRepresentable widget preview

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

To get a preview of a `UIViewRepresentable` struct, I have the following code:

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

struct ViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    return UIView()
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {

  }

  typealias UIViewType = UIView
}

struct ViewRepresentable_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ViewRepresentable().previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
  }
}
```

It outputs the following diagnostics.

```
RemoteHumanReadableError: Failed to update preview

invalid TimelineEntries
```

The error is "Cannot preview in this file – Failed to update preview"

How do you solve this error?

Comment: What's the name of your widget view?

Comment: It's in a separate file where it is named WidgetExtension

Comment: I think instead of using `ViewRepresentable().previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))` you want to return `WidgetExtension().previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UIKit views wrapped in UIViewRepresentable will not work in WidgetKit.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653471?answerId=619627022#619627022